# Linq2sql blank field returned as null

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am working with an old app that is using linq to sql.

I have a work around for the problem below but I am wondering if anyone has run into this and knows what the root cause might be.

I have a linq statement which has a number of joins in it.  I don't think the statement itself is the problem since it has been working for months without the issue I'm about to describe (blank fields have been part of the data since the start).  When I log the sql generated by the context from the linq statement and then run that sql in sql server managment studio, I have one column which has some fields that are blank.  By blank I mean string.empty not NULL.  None of the rows are NULL as verified by adding a 'where' clause that filters out NULLs.

However when that statement then gets mapped to entities by the linq2sql framework, some of the entities have that field set to string.empty some are set to NULL.  I have verified that those which are set to NULL on the c# side are in fact BLANK on the sql server side.

I have a loop that goes over the results and sets all NULLs to string.empty after the query is returned as a list, but it would be nice if there was a more elegant fix for this.

Comment: Could you please clarify which combinations of blank and null are there in your tables, an how your query with the joins look like?!

Comment: That's the issue, there are no nulls in the problematic field in the database, only blanks (string.empty).  Lets call the problematic field FirstName for ease of discussion.  The joins don't really play into this (or shouldn't) since the table that all the other joins (left joins) connect to is the one where I am getting FirstName from.  So what I mean is that FirstName comes from the table that always returns data, all the other tables are left joined to it and could have a mix of null and empty fields depending on whether the join succeeded.